# List type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a ASP.Net Core MVC with 3-Tier achitecture project for my work and I have the CS00012 error. 
I have a library called DAL that contains all the Models that I use with entity to communicate with my database and when I try to use my DAL in a test method, I have the following :

"The type 'List<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.".

I tryed to find a solution but I can't find anything that work.
Could you please help me ?

Here is my project folder :
[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtSAZ.png)

This is my function that return a List of "ConsultantSource" :

```
public List<ConsultantSource> GetListeConsultantsSource()
    {
        return Bdd.ConsultantSource.ToList();
    }
```

And this is my test method :

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestConsultantSource()
    {
        RHDal dal = RHDal.GetRHDal();
        ConsultantSource consultant = new ConsultantSource
        {
            Adresse = "plop",
            Cp = "33000",
            Cv = "plop",
            Mail = "plop.plop@plop.com",
            Nom = "plop",
            Pays = "Plop",
            Prenom = "plop",
            Salaire = 1000,
            Telephone = "0102030405",
            Ville = "plop"
        };
        int count = dal.GetListeConsultantsSource().Count;
        dal.AddConsultantsSource(consultant);
        consultant = dal.GetConsultantsSource(consultant.Mail);
    }
```

PS : Sorry for my English, I'm French and I don't talk english for a long time.

Comment: add reference of modal in you controller.

Comment: Make sure all your Project having same Target framework

Comment: @AsifRaza i think you're commenting on the wrong question.  This doesn't involve modals or controllers.

Comment: Ops! i mean you need to look at your refferences..

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` is defined in `System.Collections.Generic`. Make sure you have a `using` statement in the code throwing the exception pointing to that.

Comment: Also, `List<T>` is defined in the `System.dll` assembly.  OP needs to add a reference to `System` if one doesn't already exist, for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm hard-pressed to see how the OP would even get the app to run without that reference. I find it far more likely that the `using` is missing, especially since a number of extensions "clean up" source code automatically, which includes removing unused `using`s.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  Apparently OP added a reference to Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I checked that and I have this statement.

I found a solution (after loosing my day to find an answer) :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility
```

Just adding this package make the project run without any error !

Comment: Are you actually using older portable libraries in your project? If not, this package is inappropriate to have.

Comment: This may work, but that alone doesn't make it a correct solution.  As Chris noted, this is an old library and should not be needed for anything.